# JavaScript return true if this word exist in the data

Tags: javascript

in this case it return true because banana in the 0 index

```
const data= ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    if (data.indexOf("Banana")===0)
```

but if banana in another index i need it returns true agian how?

```
const data= [ "Orange","Banana", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

Comment: `===0` -> `>=0`

Comment: ... or use `if (data.includes("Banana"))`

Answer (score 2):

A few methods for achieving this:

1. Using [`array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
if (data.indexOf("Banana") !== -1)
```

2. Using [`array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
if (data.includes("Banana"))
```

3. Using [`array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
if (data.some(d => d === "Banana"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use includes() function

```
if (data.includes("Banana"))
```

Comment: NB: your code is equivalent to `return data.includes("Banana")`